# Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Run spring boot application

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in Car required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be foun

```
    @Component
public class Car implements Driver {

    private String name;
    private int color;

    @Autowired
    public Car(String name, int color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking Spring to provide the host, port and caFile of the car. Where and how should it find them? This class should probably not be a Spring bean. BTW, a Car is not a Driver, so the design looks wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet It has nothing to do with it

Comment: click on "String name" , view message: Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.

Comment: also, click on "int color" , view message: Could not autowire. No beans of 'int' type found. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.

Comment: If you know better than we do, why do you ask? It does have everything to do with it. You're asking Spring to inject a String and an int into your Car bean. It can't possibly guess what it's supposed to inject. That's what the error tells you: "Parameter 0 of constructor in Car required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found".

Comment: 0excus me @JBNizet, what is rahul now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to inject a Car object as component then you should provide its parameters like String name and int Color, then you might add on some configuration manager by following these steps:

1. Remove both @Component and @Autowired annotations.
2. Need to create a bean as shown on some configuration manager class as configuration.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class ConfigurationManager {

        @Bean
        public Car car() {
           return new Car("Default", 1);
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to use this Component elsewhere and set it up there:
for example: main class by "Autowired"

Comment: Yes, if you use this example as bean, so you can call it on any class in spring context, so call it @Autowired and it'll work

Comment: No problem, xD it's nice whenever it's necessary :P

Answer (score 5):

I have faced a similar issue. I replaced the constructor with getters and setters to assign the values. it worked..